# Macro to apply Serial No IF ISBLANK

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have applied a macro to insert serial no IF ISBLANK Cell and Here I know we can apply this with formula also why I have applied a macro to insert serial no IF ISBLANK Cell
because I want to insert serial no automatic with applying the macro that's why I have created a macro for this and here is a problem I have getting
(Compile Error: Argument Not Optional) in this macro

here I want when the macro applied serial no and then the formula should be hidden in that cell range

```
Sub SerialNo()
  Dim LastRow As Long
  LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
  With Range("A1:A" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISBLANK(RC[1]),"""",COUNTA(R1C2:RC[1]))"
  Range.Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim MyFormula As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    '~~> This is your formula
    MyFormula = "=IF(ISBLANK(B1),"""",COUNTA($B$1:B1))"
    
    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
  
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Formula = MyFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

If you want to convert the formula to values later, you can use

```
.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value
```

**Note:**

1. Use `Objects`. Much easier to handle and understand your code.
2. While `R1C1` notation is good, I prefer `A1` notation. Makes it easier to see which cell(s) my formula is referring to. (*This is just my personal opinion and is no way of implying that this is the best way to handle this situation. Ultimately it is a personal choice*)

Comment: No you are nto supposed to replace it. Put the line `.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Value` after the line `.Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Formula = MyFormula`