# Excel VBA: Copying Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am kinda new to VBA coding, and I hope that I get your assistance.

Basically, I am trying to copy a formula in "E1" then pasting the formula to beyond E2 depending on the counts on Column D. Like if Column D has data in D1:D(x), I would want the formula from "E1" to be copied to E2:E(x), and so on.

Comment: I just answered a similar question. See [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69240683/macro-to-apply-serial-no-if-isblank) question. This shows you what you need. `.Range("E1:E" & Lastrow).Formula = .Range("E1").Formula` Where `LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.